# git: Detect changes, including added files in my repo

Tags: git

I would like to run a script that checks if a given git repository has any changes not committed. I would also like to check for any files not added to the index.

`git diff-index` works for changes but I haven't found how to use it for non tracked files. Is there any command I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git status --porcelain`.  This shows all the information in `git status`, but in a machine-readable format.  If your Git version is new enough, you can use `git status --porcelain=v2`, which has additional information.

Generally, if there's no output, no changes exist.

Both formats are documented in the `git-status(1)` man page.

Comment: Ok so just procelain and check that the output is empty to determine that no changes exist?

Comment: Yup.  If the output is empty, no changes exist.